# Improve translate better for website

Tags: javascript, html, web, translate

I have a my own website, and i use google translate on it, but the result is not good. I use the contribute and try to improve the translation content. But after that, there is no change. Could any body help me. Thank you very much

I do the same as this

https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2012/05/now-you-can-polish-up-googles.html

But it do not know how to sign in.

Comment: I use it for a church website that is for a Greek church. I had to have someone translate all of my pages into Greek because some of the Google translate didn't come out right.

Comment: I do the same as this

https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2012/05/now-you-can-polish-up-googles.html

But it do not know how to sign in.

Comment: upi sign in with your gmail email account

Answer (score 1):

Suggested improvements aren't automatically applied, and probably aren't even ever applied specifically to the website they were suggested for. They are used by Google's developers to improve the software in general.

Automated translation software simply isn't good. It never has been and it has a long way to go before it is.

If you want good quality translations of your website, then get it translated by someone who is fluent (and preferably a native speaker) of the target language.

Comment: I do the same as this

https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2012/05/now-you-can-polish-up-googles.html

But it do not know how to sign in.